# 'Do you want to see it!' - Which type of sentence is this? Why exclamation mark at the end of a question?

Tags: sentence-construction, exclamatives, question-marks

I am a beginner, but my knowledge says that Do and Does come at the beginning of a question. Simply put, to my mind, the sentence should be

**Do you want to see it? rather than Do you want to see it!**

Am I correct? I am confused because this sentence is written on [The World Beast](https://www.theworldbeast.com/write-for-us) news website:

> Recently we launched TWB Photos, Do you want to see it! Visit NOW

I am aware of 'what a life!' kind of explanatory sentences. Is this a similar use?

Please enlighten me about this type of usage.

Answer (score 2):

I would not say that this compares to *What a life [it is]!*, which is not actually a question but an exclamatory statement.

The use of a comma between *Photos* and *Do*, rather than a period, adds to my lack of confidence in the authorial and editorial skills of whoever wrote it or allowed it to be published.

In my mind, the entire thing should actually be written as follows:

> Recently we launched TWB photos. Do you want to see it? Visit NOW!

In short, it should be three sentences, ending in, respectively, a period, a question mark, and an exclamation mark.

While liberties are often taken with headlines and slogans, the published version seems to go beyond normal editorial style.